# Mysql query variable syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass a variable to a very basic mysql query. but php doesnt return a true value. nothing.

i have checked everything

the problem is here.

the syntax of $a varible typing into mysql query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,floatingnumber FROM posts WHERE id='$a' LIMIT 1");
```

when i change $a to 22 it returns a value otherwise nothing.

exact query is here...

```
$a=$this->post_id;
$result = mysql_query('SELECT floatingnumber FROM posts WHERE id="'.$a.'" LIMIT 1')or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

  $sdfa=$a.'-'.$row[0];
```

$sdfa returns "86 -  " without quotes 86 - space

so the problem is on the mysql fetch row please help

Comment: So what does that tell you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried echoing the query to see what the real value of `$a` is?

```
echo "SELECT id,floatingnumber FROM posts WHERE id='$a' LIMIT 1";
```

Have you tried checking for errors?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,floatingnumber FROM posts WHERE id='$a' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, you shouldn't even be using mysql_* as it's deprecated.

This is how you'd do it in PDO:

```
$stmnt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,floatingnumber FROM posts WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1");
$stmnt->bindValue( ':id' , $a , PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmnt->execute();
$result = $stmnt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: well then your $a doesen't contain what it should. debug $a to see what went wrong

Comment: $a is containig 22 value but when i tried to use in mysql npothings return

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,floatingnumber FROM posts WHERE id='".$a."' LIMIT 1");
```

if your `$a` is a number then do like that

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,floatingnumber FROM posts WHERE id= $a  LIMIT 1");
```

**EDIT :**

your code is right

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

      $sdfa=$a.'-'.$row[0];
```

the problem is in your sql or table because there is no `floatingnumber` where id is `86` .

Comment: but i see that your problem is solved since you accepted the navnav answer . i edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

typically when I'm writing in double quotes, simply putting in the variable works:

```
"... $1 ..."
```

but also, I originally learned it with brackets

```
"... {$1} ..."
```

you can try that. also, a handy way to write queries is store the query string in its own variable so you can easily print out the query and see what you wrote before submitting.

```
$query = "SELECT id,floatingnumber FROM posts WHERE id=$a LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query( $query );
```

This helps identify things like this.